# How do I see my hyper link preview at the bottom of firefox?

Tags: firefox, hyperlink

I used to be able to see where a hyperlink was pointing to at the bottom of firefox. Ive got firefox 4 and there is no bar now annoyingly.

This is related to programming because I need to see wher hyperlinks go.

Comment: I see a tooltip coming up in the bottom left corner of the page when I hover over a link. Does that not do? That said, it *is* off topic here, voting to migrate to superuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The status bar has been removed.  You can get it back via an [add-on.](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/235283/)

Answer (score 0):

Strange with me it shows the links when I hover over the links with the mouse.  It just shows up at the bottom-left and just takes the size of the links, not the entire width of the screen like the status-bar used to do.

If you only need to see the hyperlinks then this should be enough if not install the extension mentioned in the other answer.

[image: screenshot],

to get the bar back at the bottom you can do **view > toolbars > add-on bar**, but that doesn't give you a link preview and it seems not to be the same as the status bar anymore.  So statusbar and add-on bar are two different things now.

Answer (score 0):

To recover the old used and very useful status bar, first, install the Status4evar (S4E) add-on.

Next step you have to open the personalize window to be sure that at the bottom will be a "variable space" line , 
at its left side you drop/draw the "status text" and close that personalization.

now you can see the complete link by mouseover as known in old days .

good luck